# Several bootstrap carousels + keyboard controls

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There's a blog I am working on with several Twitter Bootstrap carousels. I am using the following code in order to enable keyboard controls:

```
<!-- Script: Carousel Keyboard controls -->

<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {

      if(e.which==39){
        jQuery('a.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
      }   

      else if(e.which==37){
        jQuery('a.carousel-control.left').trigger('click');
      }

  });

</script>
```

This works like a charm. However, since there are different carousels once I start using keyboard controls, all carousels change at the same time.

Is there a way to fix this?

This is the site I'm working on: http://rubenparra.com/blog/

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want only one to scroll? The visible one? What if there's more than one visible?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you are triggering click on all left (or right) buttons at the same time so of course all the carousels change at the same time.

You can use the carousel ID to prevent this, if you want to a specific carousel to change at a time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which==39) {
        jQuery('#carousel-4627 a.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
    } else if (e.which==37) {
        jQuery('#carousel-4627 a.carousel-control.left').trigger('click');
    }
});
</script>
```

Also Bootstrap carousel provides methods to do this a bit more elegant:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which==39) {
        jQuery('#carousel-4627').carousel('next');
    } else if (e.which==37) {
        jQuery('#carousel-4627').carousel('prev');
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this issue.

First you need this script to see which carousels are currently visible.

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right  bounds.right || viewport.bottom  bounds.bottom));

};
```

Now, you need to bind the keys

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function (e) {
$('.carousel').each(function () {
    if ($(this).isOnScreen()) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            $(this).find('.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            $(this).find('.carousel-control.left').trigger('click');
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

`return=false` causes only the first visible carousel to rotate. 
`return=true` will cause all visible carousels to rotate.